# .Net Core Binding

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am using .Net Core 2.1. This is the function that takes the value of the input boxName from the user and is supposed to pass it to the controller - Create function when the "save button" is clicked.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Submit() {
    var boxName = $("#boxID").val();
    alert(boxName);
```

*UNTIL HERE EVERYTHING IS FINE - THE ALERT RETURNS THE CORRECT VALUE*

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: '/Box/Create', 
        datatype: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ ID: "@Model.Id", BoxName: boxName }),
          success: function (response) {

              alert("Box created");
          }

      error: function (response) {
          alert("error");
      }
});

}
```

*IN THE CONTROLLER*

```
    public ActionResult Create(int ID, string BoxName)
    {

       Box _Box = new Box();   
      _Box.Name= BoxName;
      _db.Boxes.Add(_Box);
     _db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");


    }
```

*THE STRING BoxName RECEIVED AS A PARAMETER FROM THE AJAX IS NULL*

I even tried

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,BoxName")] Box Box)
```

but it didn't work either. The error was

> Include is not a valid named attribute argument

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the content Type and don't use stringify. So your ajax call becomes

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Box/Create', 
    datatype: 'json',
    data: { ID: "@Model.Id", BoxName: boxName },
      success: function (response) {
          alert("Box created");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is partially wrong though you should do it for clarity. If there is only one action and the verb is not specified in your controller, the action is done anyway regardless if it's POST or GET.

You are using a POST verb in your ajax, by default all actions in the controller are GET. Add the [HttpPost] attribute above your controller action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int ID, string BoxName)
{
...
}
```

Comment: It is already added but I didn't include it in my question. The debugger is reaching the function but is giving a null parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a binding from the body of the request : ie:

```
class CreateBinding {
public string ID { get; set;}
public string BoxName { get; set; }
}
```

And in you controller:

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Create([FromBody] CreateBinding binding)
{
 var id = binding.ID;
 var name = binding.BoxName;
....
}
```

Comment: This is not necessary.